# Can I build for the Windows Mobile platform using Trigger.io Free Trial

Tags: trigger.io

I just signed up for a new [trigger.io](http://trigger.io) account and am using the free trial.

I want to know, if

1. I will be shown a splash screen with trigger.io branding on my app if am building on the free trial version,
2. I will be able to build for iOS, android and windows
3. I will be able to upgrade once I have an app ready and get access to al additional OS' with my old code written during my free trial.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From my experience with Trigger.io...

1. Yes you will have a trigger.io splash screen. Your own custom splash screen is a 'premium module'
2. You will be able to build for iOS and Android (and web/browser). Windows is premium
3. All your code is kept locally, so you keep that on your own machine / SVN - and yes could use the same code that you wrote in the trial.